# Sum of two columns from pivot

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, pivot

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX),@columns1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),@columns2 NVARCHAR(MAX),@columns3 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = '1,2,3,4';

SELECT @columns1 =
 STUFF(( 
 SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(Value)
FROM dbo.SplitString(@columns,',')

FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

select @columns2 = STUFF(( 
 SELECT  ',p.' + QUOTENAME(Value)
FROM dbo.SplitString(@columns,',')

FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');
                        select @columns3 = STUFF(( 
 SELECT  ',p1.' + QUOTENAME(Value)
FROM dbo.SplitString(@columns,',')

FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');    
SET @sql = N'
    SELECT distinct ' + @columns2 + ', p1.*

       FROM  
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      [CALF_AN]
          ,[CALF_NPERIODE]
          ,[CNT_ID]
          --,[PER_ID]
        ,[MontantAccoss]
      from [Reporting].[dbo].[TEMPAccoss]
      WHERE  [CALF_AN]=2014
    ) AS j
    PIVOT
    (
     sum([MontantAccoss])
      for [CALF_NPERIODE] in ('+@columns1+')
    ) AS p  ON p.CNT_ID = COT1.CNT_ID 
     INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      [CALF_AN]
          ,[CALF_NPERIODE]
          ,[CNT_ID]
          --,[PER_ID]
        ,[MontantHorsAccoss]
      from [Reporting].[dbo].[TEMPHorsAccoss]
      WHERE  [CALF_AN]=2014
    ) AS j
    PIVOT
    (
     sum([MontantHorsAccoss])
      for [CALF_NPERIODE] in ('+@columns1+')
    ) AS p1  ON p1.CNT_ID = COT1.CNT_ID;';
    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

I am looking to perform a sum `sum([MontantAccoss])+sum([MontantHorsAccoss])` of every column from pivot p and pivot p2 ?In my case select `p.[1]+p1.[1],p.[2]+p1.[2],p.[3]+p1.[3]`. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps create a `@columns4` like this:

```
SELECT @columns4 = STUFF(
  (
    SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME('total' + Value) + '=p.' + QUOTENAME(Value)
                                             + '+p1.' + QUOTENAME(Value)
    FROM dbo.SplitString(@columns,',')
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
  1,
  1,
  ''
);
```

(or modify the `@columns3`, which currently seems to be unused by your code) and add it to the main query.